# Google Vision API Capture image with graphic overlay

Tags: android, google-api, google-vision

Im using one of api face tracker sample and i modified code a bit to see if it will work according to my idea for app. what i want to do is i want to add face masks after detecting face.

What i've done so far, i've added a sample mask drawable and when i detect a face instead of drawing face points i draw drawable in face tracking rectangle. now its showing that mask in preview on the face but when i try to capture that image it only capture frame from camera not with graphic overlay i added mask on. is there any way i can capture from camera with that mask on it ?

[Image being saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sm6j.jpg)

[image being displayed on mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Puf.jpg)

Comment: I am also trying same thing. Let me know if you have achieved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved something similar to this in a project i worked on in the past but no longer have access to the project.

when you call your capture method you need to store a reference to the position of the face.

Im not sure how much control the vision api gives you over the camera so you either:

take the picture and before saving the file add the mask resource on top of the returned bitmap.

**or**

load the saved file add the mask resource on top of the it.

I will have a look around later for some code if it will help.

**Edit Rotate Bitmap**

```
bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface("/storage/emulated/0/Pic.jpg");     
String exifOrientation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
int i = Integer.parseInt(exifOrientation);
bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, i);
```

//

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bm, int i) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (i) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            return bm;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            break;
        default:
            return bm;
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bm.recycle();
        return bmRotated;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and yes i did something similar already. but there were many problems while doing so. some devices camera give rotated or even inverted image when i captured.

Comment: @UsmanGhauri I had the same issue re. the rotation of the image. I have added code that solved this on all devices i tested on.

Comment: I tried with your code but it is giving black image as it is surface view. Do you have any other solution for this...?

Comment: @mVJ are you getting any exception? the code above does not do anything with the image (apply it to a surface view) just fixes the orientation

Comment: @drojokef as i mentioned in the answer i am no longer working on this project.